# Visual Studo and IIS not recognising my install of .Net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to run an application built for .net core 2

I can run the application but when I access it from the browser I get:

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

To install missing framework, download: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.2.8&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

I follow the link, download the installer and run it.

It goes through with no errors.

I reboot and then rerun my web application but still get the same error.

Trying to find where .net core 2 was installed.

Folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

has only:

[image: Installed .net cores]

If 2.2 did install where did it go?

Did it fail silently since 2.2 reached the end of life Dec 2019?

Comment: You not only need .NET Core 2, but also ASP.NET Core 2 on top of it, as as you saw yourself, you only have versions 6 and 7 of those, that's the error.  [Look here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/2.0) for the official download links.

Comment: you can use the command `dotnet --info` to see your installed runtimes and SDKs.
check if you see that version you need on both runtimes and SDKs

Answer (score 0):

Follow your steps, I also not found the `2.2.8` folder inside `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`. But I can see it in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App`. I specifically observed the message that the installation was successful, showing the path.

[image]

EventViewer is our friend, you can check the application logs and share with us. Please hide the sensitive information if the scrrenshots needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have downloaded .net core sdk from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-2.2.207-windows-x64-installer